# An .exe application throws an error while creating a new module in windows10 but works fine in windows7?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, registry, exe

I have installed the an exe (windows application) in windows 7 and works fine there but after installing the same exe in windows 10 it's throwing an error in creating a new module in that .
The application is developed using *C++ and C#*.

Error :

**runtime error - '-2147024770 (8007007 e)'
the specified module could not be found.
could not load file or assembly def.dll' or one of its dependencies. the specified module could not be found.
File " abc\xyz.cpp
Line : 779**

Comment: at a guess `def.dll` or one of its dependencies is missing. try using dependency walker to find out what

Comment: Alan, could you please suggest me anything without installing any application? Thanks for your revert.

Comment: No without any details, if you want help we'll need a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

After Installing **Microsoft Visual c++  Redistributable Package 2012 (X64)** the application started working properly.